# Migration Swift/UIKit to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, architecture, swiftui

This could not be a question but more of a suggestion from experience if anyone did the same I wants to achieve.    Wants to understand the below point if I migrate from Swift to SwiftUI

- If UIKit class (UIViewControllerRepresentable) become SwiftUI's component,  can it use all of its feature i.e property wrapper, @environmentobject, etc?
- Getting and fetching data/events from UIKit based modules (Each feature is a module and installed as a pod in-app)
- Can my existing structure(MVVM with Bidirectional POP), totally replaced by SwiftUI reactive manner?
- Or the best way to adopt the SwiftUI, replacing protocol with an event-based app.

Any side effects?
Please suggest.

Comment: If you have those questions then you should not. UIKit are not going to die in observable future.

Comment: Totally acceptable, But my current organization very eagerly wants to move on SwiftUI.

Comment: Who pays the piper calls the tune... well... 100% migration will not be possible for now due to *youth & restrictions* of SwiftUI, but integration and smooth gradual replacement really can be started.